# How to find the equation of ellipse and hyperbola using complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, conic-sections

![I tried to solve the given questions with the help of complex but unable to get the answers. could anyone help me out to solve the both question based on given three conditions ..thanks][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6n2t.pngstrong text

Comment: Do you have any more conditions for the complex numbers?

Comment: @NP-hard, there're some conditions for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ given in the raw picture.  Don't erase all.

Comment: @NgChungTak Thanks for your reminding.